# Mongodb Groupby not working with nested fields

Tags: java, mongodb, group-by, mongodb-query, nosql

I have created a aggregation pipeline, which consists of $match, then $ unwind to select nested fields and then $groupby. Unfortunately, it says “details.locatime” contains a . and thus it seems the unwind is not working as expected. The collection structure is :

```
classroom:
  details: {
    localtime: ,
    subject: ,
    activity_id
  }
```

I want to group based on activity_id but select all the $first elements even if it is a nested field.

Comment: can you post your aggregation

Comment: Your structure shows `localtime`, and your error shows `locatime`, can you check this what's exactly there?